# Is there a way to use scrypt with password included in a one-liner?

Tags: gnome-terminal, scrypt

Is there a way to use scrypt with password included in a one-liner?

Hello,

I want to use scrypt on a file or directory. I want the password to be included in the one-liner. According to man scrypt it might be possible to use a password from stdin. But I'm not sure about how to do this.

If you know how to write a one-liner that uses the scrypt tool to encrypt a file with password included, please post here.

I do not want to fill out the password manually each time as I am doing some automation.

Tried, not working:

scrypt enc -P test-file test-file-sc

Vesa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this with the `scrypt` command:

```
scrypt enc -P e.txt e.txt-sc <<< "koko"
```

Information:

```
-P: Always read passphrase from stdin, and do so only once even when encrypting
<<<: Gotten from stdin (redirect stdin input stream)
"koko": passphrase
```

Source:

```
man scrypt
```

Comment: Cool. I tried to do something with the triple arrows too but I didn't know where to put them. This seems to work.